# CSS-only layout solution (flexbox?)

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

While there is a simple solution for this with javascript, I'm hoping to find a CSS-only solution (using CSS3, flexbox layout most likely).

If the parent box (or screen) is wide enough I want to have the following layout:

```
|<-                              100% width                                             ->|
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| P1 - fixed width | P2 - min width, grow as needed | P3 - fixed width | P4 - width width |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

However if available width is less than P1 + P2 + P3 + P4, then the layout should change to

```
|<-                        100% width                                ->|
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
| P1 - grow to 100% width                                              |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
| P2 - min width, grow as needed | P3 - fixed width | P4 - width width |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
```

For the sake of argument, let's assume that the parent will always be at least P2 + P3 + P3 wide.

I was thinking about putting the four boxes into a flex parent, setting `flex-grow` to 0 for the fixed width children and to 1 for P2.  I would then add them in a reverse order and set `flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse`.  This would push P1 onto a separate row if there's not enough space, but how do I make it to grow to 100% width?

I would really like to avoid javascript here, but, if needed, I'll do it as a last resort.

Comment: Would the parent box have a fixed max-width to begin with or are we dealing with a fullscreen width?

Comment: @chdtest Parent box width is set as `calc(100% - 20px)`, so it's screen-width dependent.

Comment: You're not looking for something like this, right? http://jsfiddle.net/6y5hn/7/

Comment: You can just use calc

Comment: @chdltest Yeah, something like this, but with min-width for the second box. The first box should wrap onto its own line if otherwise box 2 would become smaller than its min-width - regardless of the overall width of the parent.  However your solution may be the next best thing for my case.  Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
|<-                              100% width                                             ->|
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| P1 - fixed width | P2 - min width, grow as needed | P3 - fixed width | P4 - width width |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

The above can be achieved using `width: calc(100% - ??px);` on P2 while the rest has a fixed width.

```
|<-                        100% width                                ->|
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
| P1 - grow to 100% width                                              |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
| P2 - min width, grow as needed | P3 - fixed width | P4 - width width |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
```

The above can be achieved using media queries.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6y5hn/13/

```css
#outerbox {
    width: calc(100% - 20px); 
    /** this container needs to be more than 400px wide else it will be too small to contain the boxes, also not sure why you wanted the -20px but I added it in anyways **/
}

#box1 {
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#box2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:300px;
    float: left;
    width:calc(100% - 320px); /** minus the width of the 3 boxes and 20px from the container **/
}

#box3 {
    background-color:green;
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#box4 {
    background-color:blue;
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    #box1 {
    float: none;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /** minus 20px from the container **/
}

    #box2 {
    width:calc(100% - 220px); /** minus the width of the 2 boxes and 20px from the container **/
}
}
```

```html
<div id="outerbox">
    <div id="box1">box1</div>
    <div id="box2">box2</div>
    <div id="box3">box3</div>
    <div id="box4">box4</div>
</div>
```

**@Aleks G's comment:**

> Yeah, something like this, but with min-width for the second box. The
>   first box should wrap onto its own line if otherwise box 2 would
>   become smaller than its min-width - regardless of the overall width of
>   the parent.

To get that affect with only CSS, I can only suggest figuring out what the min-width is for P2. For example, if the min-width for P2 is set to 400px, your media query to get P1 in to its own line would then be 400px (P2) + 200px (P3 + P4) + 20px (the container you gave 20px) = 620px.

Therefore, when the window size hits 620px, the following styles would take place:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
        #box1 {
        float: none;
        width: calc(100% - 20px); /** minus 20px from the container **/
    }

        #box2 {
        width:calc(100% - 220px); /** minus the width of the 2 boxes and 20px from the container **/
    }
    }
```